# How to run a script with os.sys and subprocess with passing a dict as from one module to another in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, program-entry-point, os.system

I'm trying to pass a dict with input_data from Module1.py to a script that is run with subprocess and os.sys in Python 3 in Module2.py but it doesn't work. I'm first passing the dict, input_data, to main() in Module3.py and there to Module1.py, which returns the processed dict from the main function in Module1.py, but when I then run the script, if **name** == '**main**':, with os.system it doesn't get the dict. That is, how can I pass a dict -object through main in Module3 where I first process it in Module1.py,return the processed dict and then use it as input when running the script in Module2.py through main in Module3.py ?

```
  # Module 1

 def main(input_data):
  ... code...

  returns dict_with_processed_input_data

  # Module 2

 class Parser(threading.Thread):

   ..code..

  if __name__ == '__main__':

    # input data from Module 1 should be 
    # imported and used here, function calls for 
    # workers that take the input data from 
    # Module 1

  # Module 3

     def main(input_data):

     #takes input_data and passes it to Module 1
      input_data = Module1.main(input_data )
     
      #runs the script in Module2 with os.sys
      import os
      os.system('python3 Module2.py')
```

The input_data from Module1.py is not passed to the
script in subprocess

```
#calls on function that reads the script 
#in Module2.py with subprocess


import subprocess

def get_script_data():
tmp = None

proc =subprocess.Popen(['python3','Module2.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if bool(line) == False:
        break



    line = json.dumps(line.decode("utf-8"))
    tmp = line.rstrip()



return tmp

res = get_script_data()
```

I've tried with writing a main function in Module2.py and return it to the script but it also #doesn't work with the script and subprocees.

```
  # Module 2
  def main(input_data):
   return input_data
   if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_data = main()
```

The if **name** == '**main**': in Module2 has worker calls for functions through a threading.Thread class

```
      class Parser(threading.Thread):
       """ A threading class that  executes tasks from a task queue"""
      def __init__(self,threads):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       super(Parser, self).__init__()


       self.tasks = Queue(threads)              # queue that takes the number of threads that should be generated
      for _ in range(threads): self.tasks      # generates threads for events in self.tasks
     self.daemon = True
     self.work_begin = Queue()                # worker queue
     self.work_queue = PriorityQueue()        # worker queue

     def worker1(self, *args, **kwargs):
      ... code..

     if __name__ == '__main__':
     pool = Parser(11)
     # the dict input_data needs to be imported, or read as a script here
     # to be sent through worker1  


     pool.repeat_task(pool.n_repeats,pool.worker1, input_data)
```

Comment: Why are you even trying to use a subprocess here, rather than simply importing `Module2` and directly calling a function in it with the data as a parameter?

Comment: I've tried that by first passing the dict to Module1.py, getting the processed data and then passed it to the main function in Module2.py, which returns the dict but not the if __name__ == '__main__': script in Module2.py. I need to get the dict input_data from Module1.py to run in function calls under  if __name__ == '__main__' in Module2.py, which is why I've tried with subprocess.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do — actually, I'm sure I *don't* understand what you are trying to do — but if you find yourself wanting to call the stuff inside the `if __name__=='main':` block from another module, that's a good sign that stuff should be moved into a function (which you can then call from the name=main block). (Does that thing have an established name?)

Comment: The functions under the __name__=='main': in Module2.py are workers in a Python Threading.Thread class, they only seem to run from under the script and not the main function since they gather data from all places in the  imported modules.